# Firebase read/write rule for "any" child?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database structure like this

- root

  - A
  - B
  - C
  - ...(there are many like this)

In each A,B, and C I have many of data which I pushed. In each data I have `info` and optionally `markForDelete`

- $pushId

  - info
  - markForDelete

I want to grant a permission to UID `test-runner` to only be able to remove all the pushed data with `markForDelete`. But because all the removal will be executed in one go with `.update(` from the `root` node ("updating" the desired leaf to null) I need to write a rule exactly there (read/write rule cascade)

Both the first layer (A,B,C,...) and second layer ($pushId) does not have fixed name so how can I write a rule that says "any child one layer deep"? I am sure 2 layer down from root there should be a `markForDelete` field.

```js
"rules": {
   ".write" : "auth.uid == 'test-runner' && 
        (data.ANY.val() != null && newData.ANY.val() == null) && //is a deletion
        data.ANY.ANY.hasChild('markForDelete')" //previously have markForDelete

}
```

Comment: i also want to know how to do this)